# Add item with javascript to asp:BulletedList

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, bulletedlist

I'm trying to add items to a asp:BulletedList in javascript. But after the postback the added items aren't in BulletedList.Items.

Is there a trick to being able to add items to the BulletedList on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot alter ListItem at clientside, because it is a server control.

Easiest way will be to add new ListItem using Ajax such as [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example,

[image]

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<br />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="One" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Two" />
        </asp:BulletedList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BulletedList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(TextBox1.Text));
}
```